# Microservices - how to implement search combined with security cross cutting concern?

Tags: microservices

I am trying to design a system and bounded contexts.

I have 3 microservices: `Security`, `ProductsCatalog` and `Customers`.
Each microservice own its database.

Security is a cross cutting concern used in other 2 microservices.

Question:
How to implement a search that depends on `Security` microservice?

For example, there is a complicated set of rule about who can access what resources in `ProductsCatalog` and `Customers`. So, based on the user role (and other `User` properties that reside outside of `ProductCatalog` or `Customers` database), the same search request to `ProductCatalog` and `Customers` will yield different search result.
Also, those access rule can change over time.

Is there any approach or pattern how to implement this in efficient way?

[UPDATE]

Lets say you have 3 `User` roles, 10 `User` regions, 3 `User` subscriptions and a couple of `groups & teams` that a `User` belongs to.

Now, logged user wants to search `ProductCatalog`. Additional to regular search criteria contained in parameters like `Product.Name`, `Product.Category`, etc... there are rules of what `User` can access what particular `ProductCatalog` item based on user role, region, subscription, etc...

It is clear for a single `Product` access because in that case a request to separate `Security` microservice is reasonably effective. But if we have search, it sounds extremely ineffective.

Comment: Security should not be separate microservice in this kind of scenario.

Comment: @Euphoric so how to implement it in a case where you need it in several, different microservices? Especally having on mind each microservice owns its database.

Comment: I was trying to answer your question, but the more I read it the more confused I get with the architecture you have. Can you give us more details?

Comment: @T.Sar I have updated the question. That will hopefully clarify.

Comment: Where does "User" lives? In security?

Comment: @T.Sar For the sake of simplicity, yes. Important thing is: it lives outside of the microservices that perform search itself (`ProductCatalog`, e.g.).

Answer (score 3):

You want to avoid having microservices call each other randomly and/or repeatedly.

In your case the trap would be to pass a UserId around in all your calls and have each microservice call the security microservice with that Id for more information. This would create a bottleneck at your security service.

Instead, get all the information required for the call in the top layer and pass it to the one service you want to run. In this I assume you have some top level search page that a user is using.

To access this page at all they will have to have authenticated with the security service. The Security service can generate a User object with the various groups and other properties and return that to the user. (An auth token) The user can then pass that object around as required.

Your choice is whether to pass the users token down through the chain to the product service, or have the backend of the website pull the required properties out of the user token, and use some other kind of auth for the microservice call. For example a service user. SO

1.

```
SearchController
{
   [Authorise]
   Search(productname)
   {
      var sc = new SearchClient();
      sc.Login(this.context.Auth.Token);
      return sc.Search(productName)
   }
}

ProductService
{
   [Authorise]
   Search(productname)
   {
     this.db.find("select * from product where name={productname} and group={this.context.Auth.Token.Claims("group").First()}");
   }
}
```

2. 

```
SearchController
{
   [Authorise]
   Search(productname)
   {
      var sc = new SearchClient();
      sc.Login(config.username, config.password);
      return sc.Search(productName, this.context.Auth.Token.Claims["group"].First())
   }
}

ProductService
{
   [Authorise]
   Search(productname, group)
   {
     this.db.find("select * from product where name={productname} and group={group}");
   }
}
```

If the group filter is not directly mapped to a product property simply adjust the filter accordingly

```
if(group == "whatever")
   return db.Products.Where(i=>whateverGroupIsAllowedToSee.Contains(i))
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, `Group` is something that a `User` belongs to, not `Product`. So, i guess your search query itself would be some kind of a `JOIN` where databases for corresponding microservices are not separated but reside in the same db. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm assuming there is some property of product that you relate back to the groups for filtering, like price > 10 = "rich customer" group. No info is provided, but i dont mean to imply that you join the databases

Comment: ok, now i understand. so, no, as initial post states, `Group` is a property of `User`. It has nothing to do with `Product`.

Comment: you clearly state that there is a relationship : "there are rules of what User can access what particular ProductCatalog item based on user role"

Comment: tell me the rule and i will amend the select accordingly

Comment: one example could be: `if User belongs to TeamX, has SubscriptionY and IsRegistered from CountryZ then they he only see a certain set of Products`.

Comment: there are rules, for sure. The issue is, how to organize bounded contexts (DBs in particular) in order to have that search reasonably efficient because rules are not related to `Product` properties.

Comment: what defines the "certain set of products" a user with those properties can see? replace group= {group} with that filter

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you're missing some sort of orchestrator on your architecture.

Instead of sending requests directly to "ProductCatalog" or "Customer", your system should send the request to a central, orchestration service.

This service will receive the request, and in turn ask "Security" of what this user can access.

Security will answer with something of the sort:

- Informed user can access data that fits the following criteria:

  - region X and Y
  - Subscription Z
  - Role A

Then, Orchestrator will push a request that looks somewhat like this to either Customer or ProductCatalog:

"Give me data that can be accesses by someone that can see Regions X and Y, with Subscription Z, and Role A."

The Customer/ProductCatalog service will then return the appropriate data, filtered by the *criteria* that was given to it by the Orchestrator. Those services are completely unaware of what even a "User" is.

Of course, this is a simplification. Orchestrators are very helpful for organizing hives of microservices like this, but they come with their own downsides, too. Quite often, the need of an orchestrator is a strong indicator that you may have to take another look at your system and make sure that microservices are the correct path for it.

It doesn't mean that your architecture is *wrong*, just that you have to put some extra care to make sure it is *correct.*

Comment: This seems very much like a monolith frontend, which raises the question of whether the original architecture should just be a monolith.

Comment: @pjc50 I think so, too. I was adding a remark on that line to my answer.

Comment: @pjc50 that is a valid option which i have also considered. The reason for looking the solution in microservices context is that everything else fits microservices architecture. This is the only feature i cannot find a nice solution for outside of the monolith approach.

Comment: @T.Sar something is definitely wrong in my approach or, at least, I am missing something important. Because, even with the orchestrator, where will the `ProductCatalog` service get info about `RegionX`, `RoleA`? If each microservice owns its data in a separate db, i can't wrap my head around how to do this efficiently on big data sets. (Single database approach is clear with a bunch of joins.)

Comment: @tlzg It should be already present on their database, I believe. Some data duplication is unavoidable when you take the path of microservices. It is one of its drawbacks - each microservice should be able to perform its task mostly alone, ignorant of the rest of the swarm, which sometimes means they'll end up having to store or cache duplicated data in order to work. Mind, I personally _don't think_ such a feature is one that lends itself well to microservices. When data is highly correlated, it should usually live together on the same database.

Comment: Also, mind - nothing blocks you from using a hybrid architecture (a monolith for accessing data with a swarm of microservices for other features, like payment or e-mail notifications). The all-or-nothing approach, in which or everything is a microservice, or nothing is, is a very common trap nowadays.

Comment: @T.Sar yeah, hybrid is probably something i will end up with. This feature in particular is something that db engines can shine and microservices have problems with. Thank you for your thoughts!